# Which one is the best method for implementing action on Android button

Tags: android, button, listener

I wonder how Android provides several ways to implement its button click method. At least I found 2 ways, first is using command listener on Java code, second is using `android:onClick ="method"` in xml and `public void method(View v)` in java. So my question is, which one is the best in case of simplicity and effectiveness in programming. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer "declarative" markup - granted I "only" use M$FT markup these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I heard that often defining the onClick within xml can lead to problems with proguard. Personally I feel the easiest is using a switch and case within the onclicklistener, but if the method is a lot longer then it's nice to give it it's own method so to "hide" it away. If you however need common code to run after any button is pressed (for example a UI refresh) might be better to leave it to a switch and case or if/else

// Just to add for those wanting to use OnClick within xml and proguard

Add this:

```
 -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
   public void *(android.view.View); 
 }
```

However the more obfuscation the merrier in my humble opinion :P

Comment: yes defining a switch case block will alseo make the code simpler if we have a lot of button, but what is proguard actually?

Comment: Added how to fix that problem @pst

Comment: (Straight from the developer website): The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer. Because ProGuard makes your application harder to reverse engineer, it is important that you use it when your application utilizes features that are sensitive to security like when you are Licensing Your Applications.

Comment: So in other words, I need to put these code in my app when I use onClick within the xml?

`-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
   public void *(android.view.View); 
 }`

Comment: Only if you want to add a layer of security and that would only be if you needed it for the above reason

Comment: My pleasure :) Don't forget to upvote if you find something helpful. And also if you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Java is often easier because if you end with many XML layouts (different orientations, resolutions, languages, etc.) for an Activity, you'll have to modify them all every time you will want to add, change or remove an event (a long click, for example).  The lesser the number of files you have to modify, the better it is.  Also, by keeping the naming of the various events out of the XML files, you keep them at the minimum size with just the information required to express what's really different for each layout instead of repeating some of the information all over them.

With Java, you also have more possibilities in creating your code.  For example, you could create an anonymous class and use it to capture some current state to be made available to your listener.

Finally, if you want to dynamically create some buttons/fields; you can keep your procedure for administering the events the same instead of having two different methods in different files.